# Theme Cyanide and Monokai in Sublime Text 3

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, color-scheme

How to use Cyanide Theme and Monokai Theme

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Cyanide

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Monokai

I need icons in sidebar of the Cyanide, but all color themes of the Monokai.

Repeat, i want only **icons of the Cyanide** and **all color themes of the Monokai**.

The general color of Monokai is [39,40,34].

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you need to set in Preferences > Settings - User

a. "color_scheme": *monokai*

b. "theme": "Material-Theme.sublime-theme"

Theme is the property that controls the UI within sublime, i recommend you try the material theme to begin with as the icons are pretty similar to Cyanide and if i think it comes preinstalled.

This will get you the icons but the UI background colors will be a different from the code window. The best way to solve this is to install [Package Resource Viewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer).

Note: At this time it's not available from package control for some reason, you'll have to install manually.

You can then extract the material theme assets and change the colors.